# node in flowchart created with tikz does not move

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

my node/jct does not move horizontally/vertically though I am changing x/y--what is the problem

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tgschola}%------------font YES
\usepackage[
  height=8.5in,      % height of the text block
  width=6.5in,       % width of the text block
  top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
  headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
  headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
  heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
  %showframe,       % show the main blocks
  verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, matrix, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!20]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,  ->, >=stealth]

\node (cont)[process]{CONTROLLER};
\node (sqach)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-6cm]{SQAO, Chennai};

\node (sqame)[process, below of =pro1, xshift=6cm]{SQAO, Medak};
\node (vigo)[process, below of =sqach]{Vigilance Offr};
\node (cyso)[process, below of =vigo]{Cyber Security Offr};
\node (rtio)[process, below of =cyso]{RTI Offr};
\node (grio)[process, below of =sqame]{Grievance Offr};
\node (sect)[process, below of =grio]{Secretariat};
\node (hino)[process, below of =sect]{Hindi Offr};
\node (jct)[process, below of =cont, x=6cm]{Jt Controller\\T Wing};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

after using transform command

[image]

finally

[image]

and the code

```
\begin{landscape}
% \begin{figure}[H]
% \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, transform canvas={scale=0.6}, xshift=600]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!20]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,  ->, >=stealth]

\node (cont)[process]{CONTROLLER};
%------------
\node (sqach)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-21cm]{SQAO, Chennai};
\node (sqame)[process, below of =sqach]{SQAO, Medak};
%--------------------------
\node (vigo)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-17cm, yshift=0cm]{Vigilance Offr};
\node (cyso)[process, below of =vigo]{Cyber Security Offr};
\node (rtio)[process, below of =cyso]{RTI Offr};
\node (grio)[process, below of =rtio]{Grievance Offr};
\node (sect)[process, below of =grio]{Secretariat};
\node (hino)[process, below of =sect]{Hindi Offr};
%----------------------------------------
\node (jct)[process, below of =cont, xshift=1cm]{Jt Controller\\T Wing};
\node (jcm)[process, right of =jct, xshift=6cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\M Wing};
\node (jco)[process, left of =jct, xshift=-6cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\O Wing};
\node (jcsa)[process, left of =jct, xshift=-12cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\SA Wing};
%--------------------------------------------

\node (dcsa)[process, below of =jcsa, xshift=1.7cm]{Dy Controller};
\node (rdcsa)[process, below of =dcsa, xshift=1.7cm]{QMS\\URC};
%--------------------------
\node (dco)[process, below of =jco, xshift=1.7cm]{Dy Controller};
\node (so)[process, below of =dco, xshift=1.7cm]{Store Offr};
\node (ao)[process, below of =so, yshift=-4cm]{Adm offr};
        \node (os1)[process, below of =ao, xshift=1.7cm]{OS Est};
        \node (os2)[process, below of =os1, xshift=0cm]{OS Fin}; 
\node (acpc)[process, below of =ao, yshift=-4cm]{AC P\&C};
        \node (pc)[process, below of =acpc, xshift=1.7cm]{P\&C};
\node (adm)[process, below of =acpc, yshift=-2cm]{Adm\\(Service pers)};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\node (store)[process, below of =so, xshift=1.7cm]{Stores};
\node (mt)[process, below of =store, xshift=0cm]{MT};
%--------------------------------------------------------





\draw (cont)--(-23,0)|-(sqach);
\draw (cont)--(-23,0)|-(sqame);
%-------------------
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(vigo);
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(rtio);
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(cyso);
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(grio);
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(sect);
\draw (cont)--(-19,0)|-(hino);
%-------------------
\draw (cont)--(-15,0)|-(jcsa);
\draw (jcsa)|-(dcsa);
\draw (dcsa)|-(rdcsa);
%-------------------------------------
\draw (cont)--(-9,0)|-(jco);
\draw (jco)|-(dco);
        \draw (dco)|-(so);
                \draw (so)|-(store);
                \draw (so)|-(mt);
        \draw (dco)|-(ao);
                \draw (ao)|-(os1);
                \draw (ao)|-(os2);
        \draw (dco)|-(acpc);
                \draw (acpc)|-(pc);
        \draw (dco)|-(adm);

\end{landscape}
```

I have completed the org chart as below

[image]

the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[short, nodayofweek, level, 12hr]{datetime}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tgschola}%------------font YES
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\renewcommand\headrule{%------------fancy top line of page
\vspace{-6pt}
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}
\renewcommand\footrule{%------------fancy bottom line of page
\vspace{-6pt}
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}


%-----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, transform canvas={scale=0.6}, xshift=420]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!20]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,  ->, >=stealth]

\node (cont)[process]{CONTROLLER};
%------------
\node (sqach)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-14cm]{SQAO, Chennai};
\node (sqame)[process, below of =sqach]{SQAO, Medak};
%--------------------------
\node (vigo)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-10cm, yshift=-9cm]{Vigilance Offr};
\node (cyso)[process, below of =vigo]{Cyber Security Offr};
\node (rtio)[process, below of =cyso]{RTI Offr};
\node (grio)[process, below of =rtio]{Grievance Offr};
\node (sect)[process, below of =grio]{Secretariat};
\node (hino)[process, below of =sect]{Hindi Offr};
%----------------------------------------
\node (jct)[process, below of =cont, xshift=6cm]{Jt Controller\\T Wing};
\node (jcm)[process, below of =cont, xshift=14cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\M Wing};
\node (jco)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-2cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\O Wing};
\node (jcsa)[process, below of =cont, xshift=-8cm, yshift=0cm]{Jt Controller \\SA Wing};
%--------------------------------------------

\node (dcsa)[process, below of =jcsa, xshift=1.7cm]{Dy Controller};
\node (rdcsa)[process, below of =dcsa, xshift=1.7cm]{QMS\\URC};
%--------------------------
\node (dco)[process, below of =jco, xshift=1.7cm]{Dy Controller};
\node (so)[process, below of =dco, xshift=1.7cm]{Store Offr};
\node (ao)[process, below of =so, yshift=-4cm]{Adm offr};
        \node (os1)[process, below of =ao, xshift=1.7cm]{OS Est};
        \node (os2)[process, below of =os1, xshift=0cm]{OS Fin}; 
\node (acpc)[process, below of =ao, yshift=-4cm]{AC P\&C};
        \node (pc)[process, below of =acpc, xshift=1.7cm]{P\&C};
\node (adm)[process, below of =acpc, yshift=-2cm]{Adm\\(Service pers)};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\node (store)[process, below of =so, xshift=1.7cm]{Stores};
\node (mt)[process, below of =store, xshift=0cm]{MT};
%--------------------------------------------------------
\node (dcqa1)[process, below of =jct, xshift=1.7cm]{DCQA\\T-72};
        \node (acqa1)[process, below of =dcqa1, xshift=1.7cm]{ACQA\\T-72};
                  \node (racqa1)[process, below of =acqa1, xshift=1.7cm]{AHSP\\T-72};
                  \node (racqa2)[process, below of =racqa1, xshift=0cm]{OH\\T-72\\BLT};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\node (dcqa2)[process, below of =dcqa1, xshift=0cm, yshift=-6cm]{DCQA\\T-90};
        \node (acqa2)[process, below of =dcqa2, xshift=1.7cm]{ACQA\\QMS};
                \node (racqa3)[process, below of =acqa2, xshift=1.7cm]{QMS\\(Quality\\Audit)};
        \node (acqa3)[process, below of =acqa2, xshift=0cm, yshift=-2cm]{ACQA\\T-90};
                \node (racqa4)[process, below of =acqa3, xshift=1.7cm, yshift=-0cm]{AHSP\\T-90};
                \node (racqa5)[process, below of =racqa4, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]{GA\\TRAWL\\(T-72)\\Simulators};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\node (dcqam1)[process, below of =jcm, xshift=1.7cm]{DCQA\\AHSP\\QA/OH};
        \node (acqam1)[process, below of =dcqam1, xshift=1.7cm]{ACQA\\AHSP\\QA/OH}; 
                \node (racqam1)[process, below of =acqam1, xshift=1.7cm]{MBT\\T-55};
                \node (racqam2)[process, below of =racqam1, xshift=0cm]{MBT\\QA/ OH};
                \node (racqam3)[process, below of =racqam2, xshift=0cm]{BMP};   
\node (dcqam2)[process, below of =dcqam1, xshift=0cm, yshift=-8cm]{DCQA\\Doc\\Tracked vehicles};
        \node (acqam2)[process, below of =dcqam2, xshift=1.7cm]{ACQA\\Doc\\Tracked vehicles};   
                \node (racqam4)[process, below of =acqam2, xshift=1.7cm]{COD};      
                \node (racqam5)[process, below of =racqam4, xshift=0cm]{DRG};
                \node (racqam6)[process, below of =racqam5, xshift=0cm]{R\&R};  

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\draw (cont)--(-16,0)|-(sqach);
\draw (cont)--(-16,0)|-(sqame);
%-------------------
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(vigo);
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(rtio);
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(cyso);
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(grio);
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(sect);
\draw (cont)--(-12,0)|-(hino);
%-------------------
\draw (cont)--(-11,0)|-(jcsa);
\draw (jcsa)|-(dcsa);
\draw (dcsa)|-(rdcsa);
%-------------------------------------
\draw (cont)--(-5,0)|-(jco);
\draw (jco)|-(dco);
        \draw (dco)|-(so);
                \draw (so)|-(store);
                \draw (so)|-(mt);
        \draw (dco)|-(ao);
                \draw (ao)|-(os1);
                \draw (ao)|-(os2);
        \draw (dco)|-(acpc);
                \draw (acpc)|-(pc);
        \draw (dco)|-(adm);
%---------------------------------------
\draw (cont)-|(jct);
        \draw (jct)|-(dcqa1);
            \draw (dcqa1)|-(acqa1);
                \draw (acqa1)|-(racqa1);
                \draw (acqa1)|-(racqa2);
        \draw (jct)|-(dcqa2);
                \draw (dcqa2)|-(acqa2);
                    \draw (acqa2)|-(racqa3);
                \draw (dcqa2)|-(acqa3);
                    \draw (acqa3)|-(racqa4);
                    \draw (acqa3)|-(racqa5);

%----------------------------------------
\draw (cont)--(19,0)|-(jcm);
        \draw (jcm)|-(dcqam1);
        \draw (jcm)|-(dcqam2);
            \draw (dcqam1)|-(acqam1);
            \draw (dcqam2)|-(acqam2);
                \draw (acqam1)|-(racqam1);
                \draw (acqam1)|-(racqam2);
                \draw (acqam1)|-(racqam3);
                \draw (acqam2)|-(racqam4);
                \draw (acqam2)|-(racqam5);
                \draw (acqam2)|-(racqam6);  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

the balance is to get the line coming out of the CONTROLLER node from the bottom and not from the left or right side

also if any other improvements can be suggested

Comment: Use `xshift` as you were doing for other nodes.

Comment: You could also use `\node (jct)[process, below = 6 cm of cont,]{Jt Controller\\T Wing}`. Apart from that, please make your example code compilable. Currently, there will be an error message about a missing node `pro1`.

Comment: your MWE doesn't work. Please shorten it to small but complete document, which has loaded only to your problem relevant packages. Also clean up loaded `tikz` libraries. It is sufficient to load each only once.

Comment: is there a way to scale down the entire flowchart to 75% only on thiis page--also how to change the font size to footnotesize etc

Comment: The `x` key is used to change the unit vector for a `tikzpicture`, not to set the position of a node. As mentioned above, you're probably after `xshift`.

Comment: i have used---\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, transform canvas={scale=0.6}]---but the placement of the flowchart becomes at the bottom of the page--how to correct it to center--added the picture above in main question

Comment: ok got it to center with--\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, transform canvas={scale=0.6}, xshift=600]

Comment: finally got half the table done--loading the png above

Comment: Don't use `transform canvas`. If you're not sure why, see what the manual has to say about why you almost certainly don't want to use it.

Comment: Please rather ask new question than changed this one. With edition you nullify all efforts of peoples who tried to help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a just-do-it-for-me type of question (as Zarko also said, once he attempted to answer the question)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `forest package is simply to draw:

```
\documentclass[10pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations.markings,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {draw,
            fill=blue!20,
            text width=24mm, minimum height=1cm,
            text centered,
    parent anchor = south,
     child anchor = north,
             grow = south,
            l sep = 7mm,
            s sep = 5mm,
         fork sep = 3mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
             edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
             forked edge,            
            }
[CONTROLLER
    [{SQAO,\\ Chennai}
        [Vigilance\\ Offr
            [Cyber\\ Security
                [RTI\\ Offr]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Jt Controller\\T Wing]
    [{SQAO,\\ Medak}
        [Grievance\\ Offr
            [Secretariat
                [Hindi\\ Offr]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks-- please see the figure above

Comment: Which figure? I saw below your MWE a figure which seems to me not be related to your question. I solve your problem with your MWE. My MWE reproduce your first image on consistent, simple and concise way.

Comment: its the picture i have uploaded please

Comment: No, this is request "do-it-instead-of-me". I will suggest to cloae question as to broad.